# Filter by property in Django Rest

Tags: python, django, rest

I have a model with a class property, to calculate a field based on some foreign key of the model.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    field_id = models.AutoField(db_column='_id', primary_key = True)  
    ...

    @property
    def status(self):
        opportunities = list(self.opportunities.all())
    #logic 
    ...
    #
        return status
```

I want to filter on that new field. I have read different points of view, and some of them says that is not possible directly in django ORM. I've found one solution but i don't know if exits one more efficient.

My solution would be override the queryset in the viewset if the param is in the request. Filter by a list comprehension and getting de queryset again. My problem is that I need to get all objects, calculate the status field and iterate.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if 'status' in self.request.GET:
        status = self.request.GET['status']
        queryset = models.Company.objects.all()
        objects=[obj.field_id for obj in queryset if obj.status == status]
        queryset = models.Company.objects.filter(field_id__in=objects)

    else:
        queryset = models.Company.objects.all()

    return queryset
```

Comment: What does `status` refer to ?

Comment: status get a value based on relationships with two one to many relations of company class @MikeJones

Comment: You can use [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) for your case.